# Get id of item from database, when ListView item is clicked

Tags: android, listview

I'm working with calendar application and basically idea behind this: I have a ListView of added events in particular date and what I would like to do is when I click on particular event of the day in ListView, onClick method would take that event's ID from database and start new activity with it. So I would need to pass that ID into the onClick method. I have found similar problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702638/how-can-i-get-the-row-id-of-the-a-table-in-the-sqlite-database-when-an-item-is-c), but cannot quite understand it for my case..

I have this `createBookings` method, it goes in the loop for each day where there are added events and returns list of events for the day.

```
   public List<Booking> createBookings(Date data) {
        if(data!=null) {
         .....
 ArrayList<Booking> events = new ArrayList<>();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                Integer eventID;
                String eventTitle, start_date, start_time, end_date, color;
                eventID = c.getInt(0);
                eventTitle = c.getString(1);start_time = c.getString(4); color = "•"+c.getString(7);

                if(eventTitle.isEmpty())eventTitle="(no title)";
                Booking event = new Booking(eventID,color+" "+eventTitle+" "+start_time, data);
                events.add(event);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
              }
        return events;

}
```

I would assume passing `eventID` like this would be fine:

`Booking event = new Booking(eventID,color+" "+eventTitle+" "+start_time, data);`

but how do I get it later when onClickListener is called for the list view? All I managed to do is getText value of selected item..

```
       final List<String> mutableBookings = new ArrayList<>();
       final ListView bookingsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookings_listview);
       final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);
    bookingsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    bookingsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> bookingsListView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

My Booking class :

```
    public class Booking {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private Date date;

    public Booking(Integer id, String title, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
    }

//lets say I had this method here.. would it return the correct event id 
//when called in onClickListener above?  

    public String getBookingId() {
        return ""+id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the method you have written in your model class will return you the id of the clicked object but for that you will need to get the object first,so what you can do is , inside your `onItemClick()` method get your object like below

```
Booking booking = mutableBookings.get(position); // This will return you the object.
```

Now to get the `id` you can use your method like below

```
String id = booking.getBookingId(); // Now you can use this as per your needs
```

and yes i would like to recommend to use `int` instead of `Integer` in your model class.

Comment: when I put `Booking booking = mutableBookings.get(position);` in `onItemClick()` it gives me an error :
`Required: mypackagename.MainActivity.Booking

Found: java.lang.String`

Comment: Oh i get it , at first i thought `mutableBookings` was an `ArrayList` of `Booking` class but its an `ArrayList` of String, so there is this error

Comment: where you add data into `mutableBookings` ? and when is `createBookings()` method called ?

Comment: I figured it out ! I was adding it here `for(Booking booking : bookingsFromMap){
                        mutableBookings.add(booking);
                    }`, so just changed `Booking` instead of `String` here `final List<Booking> mutableBookings = new ArrayList<>();` . Thanks for your help.

Comment: great, that you got the insight , :)

Answer (score 0):

The item of the listView you clicked has a postion, this position is the same as the book index in the list array you passed to the adapter (mutableBookings), but be careful if the list first item has a position value of 1 then you should subtract 1 to get the index value in the mutablebookings list